# Angular Component calling http on mat table on every row

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a `mat-table` with a component `app-order-statuses` on every row.

the component calls the statuses of an order from my server.

however when I load the table, the endpoint is called on every row.

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../../../Services/api-service/api.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-order-statuses',
  templateUrl: './order-statuses.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./order-statuses.component.scss']
})
export class OrderStatusesComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() order_id: any;
  public statuses: [];
  public isVisible: boolean = true;

  constructor(private ApiService: ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     let url = 'orders/' + this.order_id + '/statuses';
    this.ApiService.get(url).subscribe((response: any) => {
      this.statuses = response.data.order_statuses;
      this.isVisible = false;
    });
  }
}
```

how can I make it that it calls the endpoint only on an event for example (button click).

Answer (score 2):

That's because you've made the API call in the `ngOnInit`. This lifecycle hook gets called every time there's a change in the `@Input` property of the Component.

Just move the code to another method and call this method on the click of the button:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../../../Services/api-service/api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-order-statuses',
  templateUrl: './order-statuses.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./order-statuses.component.scss']
})
export class OrderStatusesComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() order_id: any;
  public statuses: [];
  public isVisible: boolean = true;

  constructor(private ApiService: ApiService) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  getStatus() {
    let url = 'orders/' + this.order_id + '/statuses';
    this.ApiService.get(url).subscribe((response: any) => {
      this.statuses = response.data.order_statuses;
      this.isVisible = false;
    });
  }

}
```

And in your Template:

```
<button (click)="getStatus()">Get Status</button>
```